# Symfony2 and Marketplace Web Services

Tags: php, symfony

I created script which uses Amazon Marketplace Web Services and I want to put it inside a controller indexAction() function. However when I do this it says that

```
Class 'MarketplaceWebServiceOrders_Client' not found in path_to_my_bundle
```

How can I load this class in correct way? Should I place

> amazon-mws-v20090101-php-2012-09-28.*V386158529*
>
> amazon-mws-v20110101-php-2012-09-28.*V386158559*

folders under vendor folder and register it somehow?

Answer (score 0):

You have problem with your include path, Set include_path in php.ini. or If you show your code then we can help you to find out the problem.